# Player$OnAudioFocusChangedListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm building a music app, it can play song normally but recently, app will be crashed and show error :

Attempt to invoke interface method 'void vn.mymusic.android.store.media.player.Player.setOnAudioFocusChangedListener(vn.mymusic.android.store.media.player.Player$OnAudioFocusChangedListener)' on a null object reference

This error is rarely happen but i really want the reason why and solution for fix it.

```
    reset();
    releaseAudioEffectors();
    try {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            mPlayer = mDetector.getPlayer(trackPath);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    if (mPlayer == null) {
        LogEx.d(TAG, "Player not found:" + trackPath);
        skipError();
        return;
    }
    mPlayer.setAudioFocusEnable(true);
    mPlayer.setOnAudioFocusChangedListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mPlayer.setNotificationIntentInfo(ACTION_PLAY, getPackageName(), PlayerFragment.class.getName(), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    mPlayer.setWakeMode(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    mPlayer.setOnMediaUpdatePlayCountListener(this);
```

The override method of OnAudioFocusChangeListener

```
public void onAudioFocusChanged(int focusChange) {
    LogEx.d(TAG, "onAudioFocusChanged()" + focusChange);
    switch (focusChange) {
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
        if (getStatus() == State.STARTED) {
            mPlayer.clearNotificationIntentInfo();

            mAudioFocusLoss = true;
            pause();
        }
        break;

    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
        if (mAudioFocusLoss) {
            mAudioFocusLoss = false;
            setAutoStart(true);
            start();
        }
        break;

    default:
        LogEx.e(TAG, "not handling audiofocus change :" + focusChange);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share more code (Override method related to  AudioFocusChangeListener)

Comment: I just added the override method of AudioFocusChangeListener above, please confirm

Comment: mPlayer.clearNotificationIntentInfo();   
may be mPlayer is become null. because 'onAudioFocusChanged'  is working in case of 'player' null and start music by other app.

Comment: i understand what are you saying, i try set mPlayer = null before call mPlayer.clearNotificationIntentInfo() method , then show another error. However the currently error has noted by log at the code line  mPlayer.setOnAudioFocusChangedListener(this);